# Neither user 10004 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE

Tags: android-studio

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ultraliant.brandcommunity.jaijinendra/com.ultraliant.brandcommunity.jaijinendra.EmailActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: getDeviceId: Neither user 10004 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: getDeviceId: Neither user 10004 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
    at com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony$Stub$Proxy.getDeviceId(ITelephony.java:5371)
    at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getDeviceId(TelephonyManager.java:812)
    at com.ultraliant.brandcommunity.jaijinendra.EmailActivity.doPermissionGrantedStuffs(EmailActivity.java:198)
    at com.ultraliant.brandcommunity.jaijinendra.EmailActivity.loadIMEI(EmailActivity.java:103)
    at com.ultraliant.brandcommunity.jaijinendra.EmailActivity.onCreate(EmailActivity.java:67)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
    ... 9 more

Comment: Did you have a question? Please don't just push a log excerpt without any explanation.

Comment: it shows error on GCMRegistrar.CheckDevice(getApplicationContext());

Comment: also it shows error report on Android v6.0.....on AVD

Comment: if anyone had the same error .....http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-services-framework/google-services-framework-6-0-1-release/google-services-framework-6-0-1-android-apk-download/

Comment: @Flummox, please either add comment or reply, but do not edit with resolved solution with code.